# Is 99% Isopropyl Alcohol sold in stores really 99%?

Tags: concentration, alcohols, boiling-point, vapor-pressure, distillation

My understanding is that an azeotropic mixture of isopropanol and water is 91%. This makes sense as to why there are so many brands of rubbing alcohol sold at 91%. There are also some sold as 99%, which as far as I know is impossible to reach through distillation. Is there another process that the manufacturers are using to reach 99%, or is it just marketing lies?

Comment: Most brands I find on google sell it at 99.9% even (for *cleaning purposes*). I checked a few data sheets, inconclusive. The density they give is very close to that on wikipedia (0.786g/ml), whatever *that* means. Common sense says they sell the azeotrope, but then this stuff is not made via fermentation and distillation. :-)

Comment: Any decent chemical supplier certainly has >91% isopropyl available. Not surprisingly, higher purity costs more, but at least one supplier (a common one, no reason to name) has 99.7% pure isopropyl listed.

Comment: A few different concentrations of isopropyl alcohol are sold as rubbing alcohol. The highest I have seen is 90%

Comment: There are plenty of ways other than distillation to make pure isopropanol (or other alcohols). And most azeotropes can be broken by adding a suitable third substance.

Comment: @matt_black , an entrainer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You certainly can get high purity isopropanol, e.g. [99.99% from Fisher Scientific](https://www.fishersci.com/shop/products/isopropanol-99-9-hplc-grade-fisher-bioreagents/BP26324). However, that is about US$50/l for high performance liquid chromatography (HPLC) grade alcohol.

The isopropanol can be synthesized without water by [hydrogenation of acetone](http://www.freepatentsonline.com/5081321.html), or water could be removed from the azeotrope using a desiccant. [Membrane separation](https://www.mtrinc.com/our-business/dehydration/isopropanol-dehydration/) is also efficient. At home, [table salt ($\ce{NaCl}$) can be used to remove some water](https://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-Salt-Out/).

That said, there are a few reasons it's unlikely to find isopropanol at much greater strength than 91% at your local pharmacy:

- It is more expensive.
- It offers little advantage in home use over 91%. In fact, 70% ethanol or isopropanol is a more effective antiseptic than 91%. (Reagent grade alcohol *is* recommended for [cleaning precision optics](https://www.edmundoptics.com/resources/application-notes/optics/cleaning-optics/).)
- Water from air would slowly infiltrate most thin-walled plastic bottles, causing swelling (and possibly rupture) of the container.
- After opening, water would be more rapidly absorbed until it approached 91%.

Comment: But we do find 99% isopropanol at the pharmacy (in the US) so it is not unlikely.